# dont know how to retrieve JSON data in android (this in particular)

Tags: java, android, json

i been reading and searching all over the net, and i still can find the best(easiest) way to retrieve this JSON info, if u ask me, the structure of it is very messy coz the ID of blocks, is also a data you need to obtain... =/

```
{"blocks": 
{"305795": {"is_mature": 1, "total_score": 1, "mining_duration": "1:39:26", "date_found": "2014-06-14 18:25:27", "confirmations": 1, "total_shares": 1, "date_started": "2014-06-14 16:46:01", "reward": "1", "nmc_reward": "0E-8"}, 
 "305796": {"is_mature": 1, "total_score": 1, "mining_duration": "6:17:00", "date_found": "2014-06-15 11:29:32", "confirmations": 1, "total_shares": 1, "date_started": "2014-06-15 05:12:32", "reward": "1", "nmc_reward": "0E-8"}
}
```

the problem that i have, is that i need the Block Number as a field the same way i need the other keys... to make a basic table with all the data by rows...

i have this ATM.

```
JSONObject json_blocks = json.getJSONObject("blocks");

        //Log.e("JSON Debug", "Number of Blocks: " + String.valueOf(json_blocks.length()));    

        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();            
        // looping through All Contacts
        Iterator iter = json_blocks.keys();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)iter.next();
            String value = (String) json_blocks.getString(key);
            System.out.println("Key: "+key+" Value: "+value);
            map.put(key,value);
        }
```

but i get all the fields inside blocks as a huge string =(
Please, can someone give me some tips?... 
thanks!

Comment: Check this one http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-json-to-parse-data-into-android-application/28944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `json_blocks.getString(key)` you should use `json_blocks.opt(key)` which returns an object.  Here you can check if the returned value is an instance of `JSONObject`. If it is, cast it to it, and do the additional get calls you need to get your data.

Alternativley, you can attempt `json_blocks.optJSONObject(key)`. If a value is returned (non null) then cast to `JSONObject` and process it, otherwise do your getString call if that's what you want.

Comment: Note that thet `getString(key)` method has a convenient feature that calls the objects `toString()` method so that way you get a String if there is an object present. That is why you are getting the long string returned.

Comment: thanks so much!!! that worked like a charm =)
Iterator iter = json_blocks.keys();
      while(iter.hasNext()){
          String key = (String)iter.next();
          JSONObject value = (JSONObject) json_blocks.opt(key);
          
          //String value = (String) json_blocks.getString(key);
          System.out.println("Key: "+key+" Value: "+value.get("reward"));
          map.put(key, value.get("reward").toString());
      }

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Feel free to accept my answer :)